# How (can) I access the Microphone on the iOS the way Google Voice does?

Tags: ipad, google-voice

Apple hasn't approved Google Voice as an App so Google created a web "app". So somehow they are accessing the microphone thru the browser. The browser doesn't have access to the Mic so I'm wondering how they (and thus *I*) did that.

Only thing I can think of is something like PhoneGap or Titanium.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to access the microphone or the camera from a web app running within Safari on iOS. It may be possible in a few years once the W3C finalizes HTML5, but it's a long way off. I believe Google Voice's servers actually call your phone and then the audio runs over your phone's voice connection.

If you're willing to make yourself a minimal native app, there is a solution that will let you do most everything as a web app, using native code only for the audio-related stuff:

1. Create your app as a web app. Design and build everything so it looks great in Safari on the iPad.
2. Create a new native app that will act as a shell for your website. It can just be a very basic Objective-C app with a web view in it.
3. When your web app needs to open up an audio recording interface, make it request an url (via javascript or via the user clicking a link) like this one:

   startaudio://whatever-variables-you-need-to-pass
4. Implement the UIWebView delegate function webView:shouldLoadRequest: in your Objective-C code. Check each URI that the web view tries to load and intercept your custom "startaudio://" url. At this point, your app would bring up the audio interface in native Objective-C, perhaps over top of the website view.
5. Upload recorded audio data to your server in Objective-C (probably) and then use `[webView executeJavascript: ]` to tell the browser that the audio recorder has been dismissed.

Hope that helps!